# iApp raising exception, only in Thai

Tags: exception, internationalization, uitextview

The iPhone app I am working on is behaving rather normally, up to now.
It supports several languages,but the last one I added (Thai) is giving me trouble.

For some reason it crashes, raising an exception. It seems to happen when I modify the contents of a UITextView, but only in Thai language.

Doing bt in the debug console, I get the trace below.

Can anyone help me make sense of this?

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x0185ae52 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0185ae52 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x0241cdeb CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    frame #2: 0x0152ba75 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool) + 213
    frame #3: 0x0152bd1e QuartzCore`-[CALayer setBounds:] + 154
    frame #4: 0x000b8151 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 336
    frame #5: 0x000ca0f8 UIKit`-[UIScrollView setBounds:] + 5493
    frame #6: 0x001acb20 UIKit`-[UITextView setBounds:] + 116
    frame #7: 0x000ca64d UIKit`-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 728
    frame #8: 0x000c66ba UIKit`-[UIScrollViewScrollAnimation setProgress:] + 486
    frame #9: 0x0014b0f2 UIKit`-[UIAnimator(Static) _advanceAnimationsOfType:withTimestamp:] + 339
    frame #10: 0x0014ac58 UIKit`-[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 67
    frame #11: 0x015522d2 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 110
    frame #12: 0x0155275f QuartzCore`CA::Display::TimerDisplayLink::callback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 161
    frame #13: 0x023dc376 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    frame #14: 0x023dbe06 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 534
    frame #15: 0x023c3a82 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1810
    frame #16: 0x023c2f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #17: 0x023c2e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #18: 0x023777e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #19: 0x02377668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #20: 0x00072ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #21: 0x0000265d Cahier`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff37c) + 141 at main.m:16
    frame #22: 0x00002585 Cahier`start + 53
(lldb)
```

Comment: What is the actual exception message? The CALayer exceptions I've seen have mostly (all?) been NaN in a CGRect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But, where do I find the "actual exception message" that you referring to? I copied all I could see in the debugging console.